# GetById and CreateOrUpdate not working

Tags: go, mgo

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD with mgo (mongodb).

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type State struct {
    CustomerId  string
    CreatedOn   time.Time
    CreatedBy   string
    Description string
}

type DataStore struct {
    session *mgo.Session
    err     error
}

func (ds *DataStore) getCol(collectionName string) *mgo.Collection {

    ds.session, ds.err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")

    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    return ds.session.DB("c3po_db").C(collectionName)
}

func (ds *DataStore) GetAll() []State {

    var states []State
    ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Find(bson.M{}).All(&states)
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return states
}

func (ds *DataStore) GetById(customerId string) State {

    var state State
    ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Find(bson.M{"customerId": customerId}).One(&state)
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return state

}

func (ds *DataStore) CreateOrUpdate(state State) bool {

    _, ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Upsert(
        bson.M{"customerId": state.CustomerId},
        bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"description": state.Description, "createdOn": state.CreatedOn, "createdBy": state.CreatedBy}})
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    } else {
        ds.session.Close()
        return true
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return false
}

func main() {

    ds := DataStore{}

    state := State{CustomerId: "3", CreatedOn: time.Now(), CreatedBy: "Ivo", Description: "6"}

    ds.CreateOrUpdate(state)

    fmt.Println(ds.GetById("3"))

}
```

As result I get

```
{ 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  0}
```

It prints an empty result for GetById. The CreateOrUpdate method works partially. It only inserts a new record, it does not update an existing one.
Is it the correct way of doing it?
What can be done to make GetById and CreateOrUpdate method work?

Comment: None of your fields are exported (they start with lowercase letters), so none of them will be serialized and stored in Mongo.

Comment: The fields are stored. As I mentioned, CreateOrUpdate method insert data into mongodb but it not update existing ones

Comment: If they're there, they got there from somewhere else, or the code you posted isn't what you're using. *You cannot serialize from, or deserialize into, unexported fields*.

Comment: @Adrian State fields you mean?

Comment: Correct. That's the type you're trying to serialize and deserialize, and it will not work as written.

Comment: I changed and now prints { 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  0}

Comment: OK. Without being able to see the updated code, I have no way to know if the changes are correct or what your issue now might be.

Comment: Code has been updated

Comment: `GetById` never references the ID you pass in to it, so who knows what record you're getting back. Your `Upsert` call should also probably just pass in the State object instead of manually converting it into a `bson.M`.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. I corrected the CreateOrUpdate method and everything went well :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below work as intended

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type State struct {
    CustomerId  string
    CreatedOn   time.Time
    CreatedBy   string
    Description string
}

type DataStore struct {
    session *mgo.Session
    err     error
}

func (ds *DataStore) getCol(collectionName string) *mgo.Collection {

    ds.session, ds.err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")

    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    return ds.session.DB("c3po_db").C(collectionName)
}

func (ds *DataStore) GetAll() []State {

    var states []State
    ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Find(bson.M{}).All(&states)
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return states
}

func (ds *DataStore) GetById(customerId string) State {

    var state State
    ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Find(bson.M{"customerId": customerId}).One(&state)
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return state

}

func (ds *DataStore) CreateOrUpdate(state State) bool {

    _, ds.err = ds.getCol("state").Upsert(
        bson.M{"customerId": state.CustomerId},
        bson.M{"$set": state})
    if ds.err != nil {
        panic(ds.err)
    } else {
        ds.session.Close()
        return true
    }

    ds.session.Close()
    return false
}

func main() {

    ds := DataStore{}

    state := State{CustomerId: "3", CreatedOn: time.Now(), CreatedBy: "Ivo", Description: "6"}

    ds.CreateOrUpdate(state)

    fmt.Println(ds.GetById("3"))

    fmt.Println(ds.GetAll())

}
```